# web api c# add new item database not exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I try to `add` -> `new item` -> `database` -> `dataset`.

but `database` section is empty online and installed too.

[image]

[image]

I installed visual studio 2017 complete.

and use proxy and non-proxy for online items, but any result :(

**Important note: It's not duplicate my project template is complete, the new item is empty**

And in the model I can't find, `DataAdapter` or `DataSet`.

Ho can I add dataset item now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No templates in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: @Bizhan It's not duplicate my project template is complete, the new item is empty

Comment: My apologies, does this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079735/366064

Comment: @Bizhan I Found the problem bro and post answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the .net core, The problem is project type.
[image]

this the problem I must use the .net framework project type.